# Nancy Cartwright's distinction

Tags: superconductivity, mathematics, models

[Nancy Cartwright](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nancy_Cartwright_(philosopher)) introduced an interesting distinction in the context of her study of the history of the evolution of our understanding of superconductivity.  She emphasized the distinction between mathematical theories (such as the microscopic BCS theory developed in 1957) and basic mathematical models (such as the London-London model of 1935). According to Cartwright, the emergence of a full-fledged mathematical theory often depends on first developing a basic mathematical model, in a step Cartwright refers
to as *phenomenological model-building* (I think she uses "phenomenological" in the sense of "empirical" but I may be wrong).  Of course the full-fledged mathematical theory is applied not to the original phenomenon but rather to the basic mathematical model.  Since I am not familiar with the physics literature, I am wondering if this distinction has been explored further in recent work.

The relevant papers are the following:

Cartwright, Nancy; Shomar, Towfic; Su'arez, Mauricio.  The tool box
of science.  Tools for the building of models with a superconductivity
example. Poznan Studies in the Philosophy of the Sciences and the
Humanities 44 (1995), 137--149.

Su'arez, Mauricio; Cartwright, Nancy.  Theories: Tools versus models.
Studies in History and Philosophy of Science Part B: Studies in
History and Philosophy of Modern Physics, Vol. 39, Issue 1 (2008),
62--81.  https://doi.org/10.1016/j.shpsb.2007.05.004.

The following useful input has been provided at the [MO.SE site](https://mathoverflow.net/a/450313/28128):

Cartwright's case study, model building for the theory of superconductivity, has been explored further in the Ph.D. thesis [The Role of Concrete Models in the Revolution in Superconductivity](https://uwspace.uwaterloo.ca/bitstream/handle/10012/9818/Chattoraj__Ananya.pdf;sequence=1) (A. Chattoraj, 2015).

More generally, one of Cartwright's former students, Roman Frigg, has developed this approach in a monograph, [Models and theories: A philosophical inquiry](https://library.oapen.org/bitstream/handle/20.500.12657/57620/9781000609530.pdf?sequence=1) (2022).

I am interested in parallel developments, besides the field of superconductivity discussed by Cartwright, where the distinction between models and theories plays a significant role.  Any further input would be appreciated.

Comment: I think that this ishow  every physicist thinks about what they are doing. You make a mathematical model that captures the essentials, and then solve it as well as you can.

Comment: Please post this in the [philosophy SE](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com) or the [HSM](https://hsm.stackexchange.com). I strongly believe you linked to the ***wrong NC***. You mean the [eminent philosopher of science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nancy_Cartwright_(philosopher))?  Please provide a precise reference.

Comment: What you describe in the opening paragraph seems to me to be what one normally does in mathematical sciences. There are three items: (1) the phenomena themselves, (2) the model, and (3) mathematical methods. One applies (3) to (2) in hopes of elucidating (1).

Comment: @AndrewSteane, What you write certainly sounds reasonable to me, but a referee of a paper I wrote on the subject warned against relying on a position as controversial as Nancy Cartwright's :-)  Perhaps the explanation is that in some fields (including those where Cartwright made a contribution), the theory is thought (by some) to explain the phenomena themselves directly, which is an attitude Cartwright criticizes.  There are similar short-cuts being made by certain philosophers of mathematical physics.

Comment: How interesting. In every science the models get refined and enriched over time, some eventually abandoned, but the phenomena remain what they are. So it is reasonable to hold, as I do, that no model so far developed in any area of science fully describes the phenomena, and it is very likely that this will continue to be the case in the future.

Comment: @AndrewSteane, Part of the "moral" Cartwright seems to draw from the contribution of
the London brothers to superconductivity is the importance of models
(as opposed to theories) in representation of the world.  This is
sometimes phrased as a criticism of the "theory-driven" view of
models; but I am still trying to understand what Cartwright meant
here...

Comment: Your first paragraph summarizes exactly what physicists normally do.  It's impossible to apply mathematics to the actual phenomenon.  Cartwright must be arguing about related questions.  This is definitely a question of philosophy.

Comment: @garyp: You are certainly a better judge than I am (not being a physicist) but the difference seems to be on the emphasis in the pair (model, theory), as I tried to describe in my *comment* above.  What Cartwright seems to argue is that the London-London model was not theory-driven, but rather the result of phenomenological model-building; the theory came afterwards.  This would seem to go against the grain of what at least some people see as physicists' task to develop theories to explain phenomena (which kind of tends to diminish the significance of models, as opposed to theories)...

Comment: ... I found Chattoraj's text more accessible than Frigg's.

Comment: This is indeed on the wrong Stack Exchange site, it should be posted over at [philosophy.se] since it has almost nothing to do with physics. Unfortunately, as it as an open bounty it cannot be closed without moderator intervention. Please consider cancelling the bounty (since no one will answer it here anyway) and repost this at the appropriate site.

Comment: @KyleKanos, I don't think there is any possibility of canceling a bounty.  Furthermore, some users here are interested in philosophically-related issues in physics, such as Andrew Steane.  If you are not interested, there is nothing preventing you from ignoring this *question.*

Comment: @KyleKanos: note also that there is very little in the way of philosophy of science that's going on at the philosophy SE.   (I would agree with your comment if there were an SE site for philosophy of science.)

Comment: @MikhailKatz philosophy questions on Physics SE have long been [considered off-topic](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/821/25301). Whether any particular user is interested in it is unrelated to it being on- or off-topic. Note further that I said nothing about my interest in the matter, just statements of fact about its off-topicness.

Comment: And I wager that you've not visited the Philosophy.SE site, as there are [over 1600 questions](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/philosophy-of-science) tagged `philosophy-of-science` (and another [~350 tagged `philosophy-of-physics`](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/philosophy-of-physics)).

Comment: @KyleKanos : indeed I visited the site, and even proposed a question there.  My impression from the site is that philosophy of science is far from their central issue.  If the term "philosophy" bothers you, there is no need to use it: I would like to understand Cartwright's analysis of the London-London model for superconductivity, and the role of models versus theory in understanding superconductivity.

Comment: @KyleKanos: I looked up the question you linked, and my impression is that no clear consensus was reached there.  Clearly philosophy should be excluded, but users expressed support there for questions that help with interpretation of physics.

Comment: To give an example: Frigg's book is too philosophical to be appropriate here, but Chattoraj sticks mostly to the physics.  @KyleKanos

Comment: No clear consensus on Philosophy questions being off-topic? What gives you that notion? There's a +9 vote on the "No" and three separate +1 "Yes" answers. That's pretty clear consensus on "No."

Comment: @AndrewSteane: I did a bit of reading and I think I understand Cartwright's approach a little better now, so I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: I just voted to keep this open, but I also can see that this question really needs to be clarified with what would you consider as an answer. I think this is part of the scientific method and thus is the fundamental paradigm with which we see all of science, and so it would be difficult to see what it is you want us to supply you with. The very definition of what a theory is, in science, is of essence to your question and well-known to bifurcate between formal definitions and colloquial usage. I am thus not sure your question can be answered as-is.

Comment: Hi @natural, thanks for your input.  My background in physics is limited but I understand that Cartwright's distinction between *model* and *theory* (with an emphasis on the importance of phenomenal models such as London-London) is somewhat controversial; see for example Beenakker's [comment below this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/450313/28128).  At any rate, my *question* is a request for a reference, so somebody aware of subsequent developments (or parallel developments)  is in a good position to answer this *question*.

Comment: I suppose that the opposition is that _model_ is not universally accepted as a defined term in physics, despite the fact that everybody uses them. Sadly, it is unlikely for us to find consensus on the definition of important terms like these any time soon. Personally, I have a set of definitions I use, but I am sure that it will be disputed no matter what is being said.

Comment: @natural, there could be various notions of "model" but Cartwright is working with a particular one, which in the case of the phenomenon of superconductivity was a mathematical model with no (as yet) satisfactory explanation at the microscopic level (which was provided two decades later).  The aspect of this that I am particularly interested in is the possibility of multiple models, and accordingly multiple theories explaining the underlying phenomenon. In such a situation a possibility arises that a reseacher's preference for a particular theory may influence his choice of model.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question is not asking about physics, but for references on topic in philosophy of science.

Comment: @JánLalinský, in the comments above I specifically mentioned that I am interested in parallel developments, besides the field of superconductivity discussed by Cartwright, there the distinction between models and theories plays a significant role.  Thus this question is about physics.

Comment: Just because you are interested in applications of these ideas in physics it does not mean the question is appropriate here. All your references are from philosophy of science. Take a look at the questions on this site - your question is obviously off-topic.

Comment: I don't think the question is about physics, it's about references to works related to those ideas of philosophy of science. That's not physics, it's philosophy (of science/physics). If you really want to understand some physics model, then please post another question where you show you work (train of thought with specific model/equations) and ask about what you don't understand there.

Comment: My references are from philosophy of science because I am not familiar with references from physics.  The goal of this question is to find such references in physics.

Comment: I find it baffling that you've had many prominent members of this site tell you that this surely isn't physics (and is instead philosophy of physics/science), yet you continue to assert that it's physics because you want it to be.

Comment: @KyleKanos, you misrepresented my comment.  Another editor claimed that my question is not about physics because most of my references are in the philosophy of physics.  Contrary to what you claim, I merely pointed out that the reasons I am citing references from philosophy of physics is because I am unfamiliar with the physics references; indeed the purpose of my question is to try to locate some.  As a matter of fact, at a parallel site a user pointed out that some work preceding Eisteinian relativity may be considered a crude model for it before the full theory emerged...

Comment: ... What I find baffling is the determination with which you seek to limit the scope of physics questions on this site, by suppressing the ones you don't happen to like.  This reminds me of one of the subjects I am currently researching, which is the religious opposition in the 17th century to the emerging method of indivisibles of Cavalieri, which caused him much aggravation.

Comment: @Kyle, you claim concerning "prominent members" is doubtful, as well.  I just checked the *reputation* level of the editors who voted to re-open this *question* a month ago.  Both of them have higher *reputation* than you do, and comparable to the other editors who just voted to re-close.

Comment: Crossposted to https://mathoverflow.net/q/450308/13917

Comment: @Qmechanic: this is mentioned in the body of the question.